# Add missing values to power query result set based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a final result set from 5 Workbook Queries in Excel.
One of the columns in this query has empty cells since during a query
merge there were no matching values to fill.

Now I'd like to create a multiple IF function that will read the adjacent columns values and try to figure out the right value to fill in the blank ones.

```
OEM No      Manufacturer
3855860141  Mercedes-Benz
310807      Sachs
6704210112  
9062411113  
0009970653  
2213201738  
9063262681  
3954100622  
6113240350  
6113240450
```

So for example in the Manufacturer column if we had the first blank cell to be b4 I'd like to fill the values with a
function such as

```
IF( len(A4) = 10 , "Mercedes",
IF( len(A4) = 11 , "MAN",
IF(LEFT(A4,2) = "81"), "Behr"))
```

Two things I'd like to do with this.

1. Fill the columns and recursively update the tables where the queries derived from.
2. Keep the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first add a column for the Length of the **OEM No**. In the Power Query Editor window, select the column then from the **Add Column** ribbon, choose **Extract / Length**.

Then I would use the **Conditional Column** feature (also on the **Add Column** ribbon) to add a series of tests and results.  In that pop-up you select from choices to generate code.  I would set it up something like:

if **Length** = 10 then Mercedes

else if **Length** = 11 then MAN

else if **OEM No** starts with 81 then Behr

Power Query writes to new tables - its better not to try to overwrite the same table.